# Laravel 4.2 + nginx 404 File not found

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, laravel-4

Why displaying error ?

I have running other laravel projects fine with laravel 5.2 but i have old project with laravel 4.2 where i am getting this error :

```
404 File Not Found
```

You can check error [here](http://blog.yourserviceconnection.com/)

On my local pc with php7 fpm working fine using Laravel Valet.

Here is my nginx config file :

```
server {
        listen  80;
        server_name blog.yourserviceconnection.com;
        root var/www/html/blog/public/;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        }
        location ~ \.(hh|php)$ {
                fastcgi_keep_conn on;
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

Looks everything fine to me, and this is .htaccess file :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw you are using hhvm so Instead adding.

```
location ~ \.(hh|php)$ {
                fastcgi_keep_conn on;
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }
```

use

```
include hhvm.conf
```

May this will help as it's default configuration by hhvm so no mistake.